# Match values in pairs from Html using RegEx

Tags: regex

I need to use Regex only to extract the following output:

- Match 1: (Group 1: Packaged Quantity) (Group 2: 1)
- Match 2: (Group 1: Width) (Group 2: 14.7 cm)

Given the following input:

```
<li>
  <div class="col-3"> Packaged Quantity </div>
  <div class="col-5"> 1 </div>
</li>
<li>
  <div class="col-3"> Width </div>
  <div class="col-5"> 14.7 cm </div>
</li>
```

So far I have tried using :

```
(?<=class=\"col-3\">)[^<]+|(?<=class=\"col-5\">)[^<]+
```

This gives me 4 different matches. But I want two matches, with two groups in each match. I know I could use xpath to do the same, but I am limited to use Regex for some constraints that I won't be able to comment on.

Comment: Using regexps to parse HTML is usually a bad idea. It still works in a simple case like this, but anything more complex will become a nightmare.

Comment: @JamesZ agree, but the situation was that I had HTML data in .txt format, hence used regex, since I knew structure would not change. Will you suggest any other way to deal with the same situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match the `col-3">` at the start, then capture non-`<` characters for the first group, match `</div>` followed by non-`>` characters, and capture non-`<` characters again for the second group:

```
col-3">([^<]+)<\/div>[^>]+>([^<]+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/YAZFvV/1

(that said, if at all possible, it would be better to use a proper HTML parser for this sort of thing)

Comment: Worked like a charm. Just a question though, regarding interpretation of Regex101.com output; Full matches should not be our concern, it is just the capturing groups we should be concerned about right?

Comment: Right, you just need to extract each group and ignore whatever the full match happens to be.